# Regular expression in Python, 2-3 numbers then 2 letters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do autodetection of bra size in a list of clothes. While I managed to extract only the bra items, I am now looking at extracting the size information and I think I am almost there (thanks to the stackoverflow community). However, there is a particular case that I could not find on another post.

I am using:
`regexp = re.compile(r' \d{2,3} ?[a-fA-F]([^bce-zBCE-Z]|$)')`
So
Possible white space if not at the beginning of the description
two or three numbers
Another possible white space or not
Any letters (lower or upper case) between A and F
and then another letter for the two special case AA and FF or the end of the string.

My question is, is there a way to have the second letter to be a match of the first letter (AA or FF) because in my case, my code output me some BA and CA size which are not existing

Examples:
Not working:
"bh sexig top matchande h&m genomskinligt parti svart detaljer 42 basic plain" return "42 ba" instead of not found
"puma, sport-bh, strl: 34cd, svart/grå", I guess the customer meant c/d

Working fine:
"victoria's secret, bh, strl: 32c, gul/vit" returns "32 c"
"pink victorias secret bh 75dd burgundy" returns "75 dd"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
 \d{2,3} ?([a-fA-F])\1?(?![a-fA-F])
```

**Explanation**

- `\d{2,3} ?` Match a space, 2-3 digits and optional space
- `([a-fA-F])\1?` Capture a-fA-F in group 1 followed by an optional backreference to group 1
- `(?![a-fA-F])` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a-fA-F

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9aCEA/1)